# read the dictionary value from array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

```
FOODS = {'Beef', 'Chicken'}

# The calories for each food item (a dictionary, where 
# key = food name (string) and value = calories (int)
CALORIES = \
    { 'Beef' : 200,     \
     'Chicken' : 140,   \
    }

class Food():
    __slots__ = (
        'name',         # string name
        'cal'           # Calories
    )

def mkFood( name ):
    result = Food()
    result.name = name
    result.cal = [calories for calories in CALORIES.values()]
    return result
```

Is that a proper way to the value of the target item in Calories? Like getting 200, 140, such like that.

Trying to get the value of the calories. That is all.

`result.cal = calorie in dict(CALORIES[1])`

Comment: Your dictionary is missing a closing `}`.  Also, you don't need the trailing \ if you put the opening `{` on the same line as `CALORIES =`

Comment: Oops. My professor wanted me to leave the `\` there.

Comment: A suggestion to pass along. You can run python as an interpreter and play around with what a command will do. Just start 'python' or 'python.exe' and type Python language code into it. Then you can see what 'foo in dict' or '[x for x in foo.values()]' will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the proper way would be:

```
result.cal = CALORIES[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dict.values`, which returns all the values of the dictionary:

```
result.cal = [calories for calories in CALORIES.values()]
```

This will result:

```
>>> print result
[200, 140]
```

Full code:

```
def mkFood( name ):
    """Create and return a newly initialized Food item"""
    result = Food()
    result.cal = [calories for calories in CALORIES.values()]
    return result
```

Hope this helps!